# Age Out/Into Report - LOOKUPVALUE Error/Confusion

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to work on an age out/into report for a non-profit YMCA I work at.

There are four tables that are being used for it:

- **Customers**. The Customers table provides information about our members. This includes Customer ID, First Name, Last Name, Age, and Date of Birth.
- **Packages**. The Packages table provides information about our membership packages. This includes Package ID, Package Name, Site (Branch) Name, Min Age, and Max Age.
- **Family Members**. The Family Members table connects the Customers to a single family unit based on Customer ID.
- **Memberships**. The Memberships table provides information about the membership that each member has and ties them to the Packages table. This includes Customer ID, Package ID, Package Name, and Membership Status.

The relationships for each table are set as the following:

- Family Members to Customers, based on Customer ID, with a many to one relationship.
- Memberships to Customers, based on Customer ID, with a many to one relationship.
- Memberships to Packages, based on Package ID, with a many to one relationship.

What I'm trying to do is show how many days until a member's birthday and if they need to be changed to a different membership package.

So far, I've done the following:

- I've added a custom column called **Next Bday** which shows the member's next birthday. If statements were used to change the year to 2024 if their birthday has already passed TODAY().
- I've added a custom column called **Days Until Birthday** which shows the number of days until their next birthday.
- I've added a custom column called **Age At Next Birthday** which adds a year to their age which was used in the LOOKUPVALUE().

In another custom column called **New Package**, I've been trying to get LOOKUPVALUE() to provide the Package Name if the member is aging out/into a different one. For example, a Youth member who turns 13 on their next birthday, should show Teen.

My LOOKUPVALUE() formula is:

```
New Package = LOOKUPVALUE(Packages[Package Name], Packages[Min Age], [Age At Next Birthday])
```

This only seems to work when I have a single row per package and its min age, as you can see in my first example, which I uploded to: [Example 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozvd0vrww6lx296/Membership%20Age%20Outs%20Example.pbix?dl=0,)

However, we have multiple sites (branches) with similar packages and age ranges, but based on an annual and monthly payment plan.

Using the LOOKUPVALUE() as is, it provides an error of "**A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected**".

I'm assuming this is because basing it off of just the min age, would result in multiple values from all of the matching package age ranges.

I tried doing the following:

```
New Package = LOOKUPVALUE(Packages[Package Name], Packages[Min Age], [Age At Next Birthday], Packages[Package Name], X)
```

I thought X is where I could add in another lookup value from the package name criteria, which the Memberships table provides, but it's not giving me the option to choose from Memberships. I also need to figure out how to check if it's monthly or annually.

I uploaded a second example to show the error: [Example 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/msb3tcahttlxge0/Membership%20Age%20Outs%20Example%202.pbix?dl=0,)

What I need to have shown is the following (using XX for values that I can't think off the top of my head):

| Customer ID | First Name | Last Name | Age | Date of Birth | Package Name | Next BDay | Days Until BDay | Age at Next BDay | New Package |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | Joe | 2 | XX | Youth - Monthly | XX | 10 | 3 | N/A or blank |
| 2 | Sam | Sam | 17 | XX | Teen - Annually | XX | 150 | 18 | Adult - Annually |
| 3 | Max | Max | 17 | XX | Teen - Monthly | XX | 25 | 18 | Adult - Monthly |
| 4 | Harry | Harry | 34 | XX | Adult - Monthly | XX | 5 | 35 | N/A or blank |
| 5 | Liam | Liam | 5 | XX | Youth - Monthly | XX | 220 | 6 | N/A or blank |
| 6 | Kelly | Kelly | 64 | XX | Adult - Annually | XX | 1 | 65 | Senior Adult - Annually |

**Edit**

I've managed to pull out Annually and Monthly with the "Text After Delimiter" column, so now I have three columns I need to be able to check with:

1. Package Frequency (Monthly or Annually)
2. Min Age
3. Site Name

Is there a way to do the LOOKUPVALUE with the three different criteria? It seems to only be able to use Packages and Customers, which is why I was having the issue where I was checking Memberships above.